# Weird Array Stuff (Array indexes getting values without me setting it)

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to write a sudoku solver.

I got the input almost done, but something strange started happening. On the index `[i][9]` of `int sudoku[i][9]`, there are numbers present that I have never put there.
For example, when I run the code below with the input that is commented below `using namespace std;`, the output is:

```
410270805
085146097
070580040
927451386
538697412
164328759
852704900
090802574
740965028
```

Of course, I only need 0 through 8, but I was wondering what is causing integers to appear at the 9th index.

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

/*
410270805
085146097
070580040
927451386
538697412
164328759
852704900
090802574
740965028
*/

int main()
{
    int sudoku[9][9];
    int solving[9][9][9];
    int input;
    for (int i=0; i<=8; i++) {
        cin >> input;
        int j;
        int k;
        for (j=8, k=1; j>=0; j--, k++) {
            int asdf = input/pow(10,k-1);
            sudoku[i][j] = asdf % 10;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<=8; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<=9; j++) {
            cout << sudoku[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: step 1. Dont use arrays step 2. Use std::vectors step 3. use the `.at()` to make sure you know that you are accessing in the vector bounds.

Comment: What are these "integers ... at the 9th index" of which you speak, anyway? Your posted output doesn't shown any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing elements outside of the defined region of an array is Undefined Behavior (UB).

That means it could:

1. Allow you to access uninitialized space (what yours is doing hence the random numbers)
2. Segfault
3. Any number of other random things.

Basically don't do it.

In fact stop yourself from being able to do it. Replace those arrays with `std::vectors` and use the `.at()` call.

for example:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> sudoku(9, std::vector<int>(9, 0));
for (int i=0; i<=8; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<=9; j++) {
        cout << sudoku.at(i).at(j);
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Then you will get a thrown runtime exception that explains your problem instead of random integers or segfaults.

Answer (score -2):

I think I found your problem, at your very last for loop you used `j <= 9` instead of `j <= 8`. You then tried to write `(j)` leaving the possibility of it writing `9` wide open. Try replacing that `9` with `8`.

Comment: I think "try replacing `9` with `8`" carried an implied "and don't introduce a new error with `i <= 9` in the previous line" with it. [Works OK if you don't do this](http://ideone.com/EklWqk). Either way, OP clearly says they know they're going to 9, so this answer is not helpful.

Comment: @_BabyBlaster_ You seriously want to [repeat the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and to have some reading [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This site isn't meant as a chatting forum!

Comment: This actually answers the question, I don't understand why there is so many downvotes on the answer.

Comment: @Frederik.L: It doesn't answer the question. The question is "why, when I go to 9, do I get these additional integers when I didn't put  them there?" This answer does nothing to address that, it merely restates what the OP already knows, which is that he/she is going to 9.

Comment: @Frederik.L Can you elaborate and [show us some working version](http://ideone.com/fork/WnTfvg) please?

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Oh, didn't see the "I know but why" part, sorry.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Your version is working if you don't iterate over i=9.

Comment: @Frederik.L Well, that wasn't stated in the answer though. Comments from other users to clarify don't make the answer itself essentially better. Could we agree on this point? Sorry I'm some times kinda shortcut with my comments. Essentially I tried to push @_BabyBlaster_  to think over, what it means asking questions and giving answers on SE.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Agreed, and pushing new members to improve their writing / communication skills have been doing an excellent job on SE since the big quality raise about 2 years ago.

Comment: @Frederik.L _'... since the big quality raise about 2 years ago.'_ Did you miss the \sarcasm tag?!? :P ... ;)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The tag was at the 9th index and didn't see it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56677/discussion-between---and-frederik-l).

Comment: The reason I put j <= 9 there was to show the problem.
And it is not writing to sudoku[i][j], it is reading from it.